# почему видеокарта работает в PCI-E х8 а не в х16

Tags: windows, железо

В биосе всё стоит по дефолту, процык i7 4770

материнка и видеокарта поддерживают PCI-E x16 3.0

где в биосе можно выставить х16? 
[вот сама системка >>](https://www.asus.com/ru/Motherboards/B85MG/specifications/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте проверить свою видеокарту на другом компьютере и чужую в своем. С большой долей вероятности у вас с картой не все в порядке. В интернете есть упоминание о зависании карт на 8x, помогала только замена карты на новую с возвратом глюкнутой карты по гарантии.

Comment: Попробуйте как работает с одним занятым PCIe слотом, возможно разработчики "схалтурили" запаралелив порты, и при наличиии паралельно 8x устройства в одним из портов PCIe (на даной mb их три), скорость меняется.

Comment: на другой материнке моя ВК выдает PCI-E x16 2.0 на чипсете h81. Это раз, во-вторых ВСЕ Сильно ошибаются, что  PCI-E x16 3.0 нужна топовым ВК, как раз наоборот у топовых большой объем собственной памяти 8Гб и обмен по шине минимален, в отличии недорогих 1-2Гб

Comment: Стоит сменить **видеокарту**. Посмотри что получится. Если ситуация не изменится, то скорее всего проблема в **материнской плате**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте в каком слоте у вас стоит карточка; 2. Посмотрите какой слот загружается первым; 3. Переставьте драйвера для NVidia (рекомендуется самые последние, от версии к версии есть существенные различия); 4. Нажмите на вопрос рядом с Bus Interface, что он напишет, возможно получится изменить в динамическом режиме.

Comment: на материнке только 1 PCI-E 16, драйвера разные пробовал и старые и самые новые.  Bus Interface под нагрузкой выдает х8 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Плата может переходить в другой режим в целях энергосбережения. Попробуйте нагрузить её чем-нибудь тяжелым (TensorFlow?) и ещё раз посмотрите после.

Попробуйте удалить все другие устройства PCIe.

Comment: под нагрузкой она меняет режим х8 1.1 на х8 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется это проблема CPU-Z/GPU-Z, у меня тоже показывает x8, однако драйвер Nvidia показывает шину x16 (Панель управления NVIDIA -> Информация о системе)

Comment: у меня тоже драйвер показывает:
Шина: PCI Express 16 Gen 3 - что и подтвердлает GPU-Z, а материнка дает только 8 - скорее всего проблемма в самом процессоре(брак или перегнули!!!!)

Comment: У меня он тоже самое показывает, хотя ничего не перегнуто, да и если честно то на Gen3 PCIe разницы нет между х8 и х16 нет даже для 1080 ( http://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/2488-pci-e-3-x8-vs-x16-performance-impact-on-gpus ) ради интереса проверю на работе, но сдаётся мне что это какая-то ошибка самого GPU-Z/СPU-Z

Comment: на ютюбе есть видео "Почему PCI-E не работает в режиме x16" из-за погнутых ножек. У меня ножки целые и даже ДНС мне поменял материнку с асус на асрок - все равно таже херня. Я уверен у меня глючный i7-4770

Comment: а в мамке только один x16?

Comment: а что за мать ?

Comment: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B85M-HDS%20R2.0/

Comment: а можно ли в вручную изменить в BIOS -> Chipset Confguration -> PCIE1 Link Speed на x16? Просто в i7-4770 всего 16 линий PCIe

Comment: в BIOS -> Chipset Confguration -> PCIE1 Link Speed - там только AUTO/Gen1/Gen2/Gen3. Я ставил AUTO/Gen3 - не помогло. И вообще это чипсет, а у него всего 8 линий PCI-E, 16 линий в самом процыке - для который нет настроек

Comment: PCIE1 это и есть x16, в мануале нет диаграммы матери, но он должен работать не через чипсет ,а прямо с CPU,